# list items in order colums/rows in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am doing tests on google-sheets and I have this script:
What it does is consult data and insert it into the sheet but it does not do so in the desired order.

what I have:
bad sheet[image]

what I want:
good sheet[image]

```js
function callapi() {


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
      for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var title = data[i].title
        var id = data[i].id
         var userId = data[i].userId
       Logger.log(title)
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue([title]);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,2).setValue([id]);
     sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,3).setValue([userId]);
 }
      
  }
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why?

Because the lastRow changes after each `setValue()`. If lastrow is 1, after `title` is set, it becomes 2 > `id` is set on 2+1 > `userId` is set on 3+1

#### Solution:

Use a variable to store the data:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lr + 1,1).setValue([title]);
  sheet.getRange(lr + 1,2).setValue([id]);
  sheet.getRange(lr + 1,3).setValue([userId]);
 }
```

Simplifying by batching:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lr+1,1, 1, 3).setValues([[title, id, userId]]);
```

Simplifying by batching up further ,

```
//v8
const data = JSON.parse(json);
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const lr = sheet.getLastRow();
const output = data.map(obj=>Object.values(obj));
sheet.getRange(lr + 1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```